# Overlap relative positioned images in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made fading slideshow in CSS3. Now I must insert it in a div container in such a way that the slideshow has width 100% of the parent, and appropriate height. If it was a single image I can easily do this:

```
<img src='url' style='border: 4px solid #dedede; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 3%;' />";
```

But in order to work the slideshow needs all the images to overlap, and the only way I'm able to find out is to position those images absolute. When I do this, the div container no longer stretches around my images, so whatever I do I end up either with stretched image or with too big or too small container when resizing the page. 
The only workaround I see is to use like 10-15 media queries to resize my div's height for each page width and keep it's height slightly bigger than the slideshow. But aren't there better solutions, because that's a bad one..
And here's my slideshow code:

```
            .slide{position: relative;}
        .slide figure{
            border: 4px solid #dedede;
            margin: 0;
            position: absolute;
            opacity: 0;
            }
        .slide figure:nth-child(1) {animation: xfade 20s 0s infinite;}
        .slide figure:nth-child(2) {animation: xfade 20s 6s infinite;}
        .slide figure:nth-child(3) {animation: xfade2 20s 12s infinite;}
        @keyframes xfade{
            0%{opacity: 0;}
            10%{opacity: 1;}
            30%{opacity: 1;}
            40%{opacity: 0;}
            }
        @keyframes xfade2{
            0%{opacity: 0;}
            10%{opacity: 1;}
            40%{opacity: 1;}
            50%{opacity: 0;}
            }
```

Comment: This can be pretty simple or pretty complicated depending on what you know: case 1: if you do know the image sizes, you can set the container dimensions to correspond with the highest with/height. case 2: if you don't know this there are workarounds depending on what you need to do exactly.

Comment: I know the used images sizes, so yes, the height/width ratio might be calculated easily. I don't know the exact size in any given moment however, as it is a responsive website and the width is something like 100% of body, whitch width is viewport - 3.5% left and right margins, something like this...

Comment: This solves the width problem. Just add width: 93%; position: relative; on the container and body {width: 100%}. The height however is a bit of a problem since it's height must be in px, or it's parent height in px. If it doesn't matter to you, the simplest way would be to set a number of px that would fit anything (about 700px or so I guess), but this comes with a problem on small monitors... it adds a scroll.

Comment: That's my point, the width is not a problem at all, but the height is. And yes, using enormous container is the problem I'm trying to avoid here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After our comment discussion, you ended up with 5 possible solutions (none perfect unfortunately since they require processing):

1. Media queries (this may be the best and since you already know how to do it even better)
2. Js resize (get largest image size and set container dimensions, this would be nice, but on slower pcs the user may notice a fast "blink" from the resize)
3. PHP dimensions set: If you have php code before loading the page you can get the image sizes there, and use it to set dimensions of the container (this is the second best I guess - is what I would do)
4. Image "cut": Set a fixed height, then use overflow hidden to clip unwanted content
5. Set a standard and use only images of that size (this may not fit your needs).

Comment: Yeah, I'll go for the JS, just I'm new to CSS, so I thought there might be simple CSS solution I fail to find, but obviously that's not the case. Thank you.